# Incorrect bytes32 to string conversion

Tags: solidity, web3js, solidity-0.5.x

My solidity function is returning a `bytes32[]` which I am looping in `Javascript` and converting to `string` using `web3.toAscii()`. Printing this in console shows extra `�` characters at the end as shown below

[image]

The function returning bytes32

```
function myBets() public view returns (uint[] memory, bytes32[] memory, bytes32[] memory, int[] memory){
    uint n = betterCacheData[msg.sender].length;

    uint[] memory betValues = new uint[](n);
    bytes32[] memory options = new bytes32[](n);
    bytes32[] memory winStatus = new bytes32[](n);
    int[] memory moneyLineValues = new int[](n);

    for(uint i=0; i<n; i++){
        uint betId = betterCacheData[msg.sender][i].betId;
        uint optionId = betterCacheData[msg.sender][i].optionId;

        betValues[i] = betterCacheData[msg.sender][i].betValue;
        options[i] = bets[betId].moneyLineData[optionId].option;

        if(bets[betId].betStatus == BetStatus.Open || bets[betId].betStatus == BetStatus.Closed){
            winStatus[i] = "pending";
        } else{
            if(bets[betId].correctChoice == optionId){
                winStatus[i] = "won";
                moneyLineValues[i] = bets[betId].moneyLineData[optionId].value;
            } else{
                winStatus[i] = "lost";
            }
        }
    }
    return (betValues, options, winStatus, moneyLineValues);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Show your full code please (the part relevant to this question).

Comment: @goodvibration I have added the solidity function.

Comment: Good, now can you please print those `bytes32` values without `web3.toAscii`, and then post them here?

Comment: @goodvibration 0x776f6e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 and 0x6c6f737400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 I just realized that all the byte32 values returned by the function have these weird characters. But these characters don't show up when I use these variables inside html page but only in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the `byte32` values to convert to string using a hex to string converter website. The website also displays these weird characters.

[image: original byte32 value]

Then I tried stripping all characters before and including `x`, and also all the `0's` and now I got the desired output

[image: modified byte32 value]

Then I tried passing `776fe` to `web3.toAscii()` and got the desired output.

**TLDR**
Use `web3.toUtf8()` instead